# How do I open a file with ansible-vault edit from inside vim?

Tags: vim, window-management, ansible

Usually, when I want to open a file encrypted by ansible-vault for editing, I just run `ansible-vault edit <filename>` - this decrypts the file to a temporary file and opens it for editing.

However, what I want to know is how to achieve this from within vim, e.g. by running a shell command using the `:! ...command...` syntax. For instance, I know that I can decrypt the file by open the encrypted file in vim, then running this:

```
:! ansible-vault edit %
```

But that opens the file with ansible-vault in a different window, and then you have to press a key to return to vim.

What I want to do is to be able to open this file with vim such that I can edit it alongside other regular files or files that are encrypted with ansible-vault. Currently I'm doing this by opening several tmux panes, but that's kind of a PITA.

Comment: Have you tried running `:r! asnsible-vault edit ...` .  Editing normal files within vi(m) would be `:e filename`

Answer (score 3):

I've been doing this from inside vim when editing an encrypted vault file:

`:!ansible-vault --vault-password-file=~/.vault_pass decrypt %`

Make a change and then re-encrypt the file:

`:!ansible-vault --vault-password-file=~/.vault_pass encrypt %`

The vault password goes in ~/.vault_pass as plaintext

To just view the contents and then go back to the original encrypted file (using git as the SCM and [fugitive.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive) plugin), first decrypt and when done:

`:Git checkout %`

I might create a function or aliases for those commands to make it quicker in the future. For now I do a command history search so I don't have to type the whole thing every time:

`q:
/decrypt
N
enter`

Answer (score 2):

I managed to do that using

```
%! ansible-vault decrypt --output -
```

To encrypt the buffer, use

```
%! ansible-vault encrypt --output -
```

It would be great to be able to automate this. I achieved some degree of success with

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *
  \ if getline(1) =~ '$ANSIBLE_VAULT;.*;AES256'     |
  \   execute '%! ansible-vault decrypt --output -' |
  \ endif
```

I was however unable to set an autocmd for reencrypting the content of the buffer at exit.

Comment: This looks great.  I'm not great with Vim programming, but could we use the BufWrite autocmd-event to encrypt the contents of the file?

Comment: If you find a way, I am interested! Unfortunately, I was never able to get it to work flawlessly.